# languageContext in front of [[+uri]] to fix the link

Tags: modx, modx-revolution, babeljs, modx-resources, modx-chunks

I use pdoTools, pdoNeighbors and babel for a multi-language Website on MODX Revo.
In pdoNeighbors I define Chunks.

```
[[pdoNeighbors?
    &sortby=`menuindex`
    &sortdir=`DESC`
    &resources=`-23`
    &tplPrev=`tplLinkZurueckEn`
    &tplUp=`tplEbeneHoeherEn`
    &tplNext=`tplLinkVorEn`
    &tplWrapper=`tplVerpackung`
]]
```

Everything works, except in the templates where I have to put the language code in front of the URL:

tplEbeneHoeherEn

```
href="/en/[[+uri]]"
```

I use http://domainName.de/lanuageCode/pageTitle.html as URL.
You might image setting up different chunks for every language-code is not effective.
Is there a possibilty to get the language-context (path) I put in for babel in system/contexts in front of [[+uri]] ?
Something like this:

tplEbeneHoeherEn

```
href="[[+languageContext]][[+uri]]"
```

Comment: how about `[[~[[+id]]]]` instead `[[+uri]]`?

Comment: Hey, that works!!! Thanks Vasis! Sometimes things are so easy, I love MODX!!!